# Get the values of a specific row from a csv file and then place each of these values in an HTML form - index error message when I run my code

Tags: python, html, csv, flask, compiler-errors

In the script below, I try to get column by column the values stored in a row of a csv file. In this case, in the code below, I try to get the values recorded in the second row of the csv file. Then, I try to put the values obtained in the csv file in an html form

Running the code below with Flask, I get the error message *Index Error: list index out of range*.

Can you please tell me how I can correct my code. Thanks in advance for your help

**Python script :**

```
@app.route("/updateform")
def prefill_updateform():
html_page = get_html("updateform")
with open ("data.csv", "r") as source:
    reader = csv.reader(source)
    data = []
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)
        option_list1 = data[2],[1]
        option_list2 = data[2],[2]
        option_list3 = data[2],[3]
        option_list4 = data[2],[4]
        return html_page.replace("$$OPTION1$$",str(option_list1))
                        .replace("$$OPTION2$$",str(option_list2))
                        .replace("$$OPTION3$$",str(option_list3))
                        .replace("$$OPTION4$$",str(option_list4))
```

**HTML script :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Form to update issue</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/add.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <p><a href="/">Go back on homepage</a></p>
</header>  
<form  action="/editi" method ="get">
<h1 id = "title updateform">Add an Issue</h1>
<br>
<div class="formbody">
<fieldset class="block1">
    <legend>Information</legend>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div><label>ID:
        <div>
            <select name="id" id="id">
                <option value="ID1">ID1</option>
                <option value="ID2">ID2</option>
                <option selected>$$OPTION1$$</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div><label>ID AH:
        <div><input type="text" name ="ah" id="ah">
        <div><input type="text" value = $$OPTION2$$ ></label></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div><label>ID CP:
        <div><input type="text" name ="id_cp" id="id_cp">
        <div><input type="text" value = $$OPTION3$$ ></label></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div><label>Value impacted:
        <div><input type="text" name ="value" id="value">
        <div><input type="text" value = $$OPTION4$$ ></label></div></div>
    </div>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting a section of your code:

```
    data = []
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)
        option_list1 = data[2],[1]
```

I'm going to walk through this. We first initialize `data` to an empty list.
Now we're going to start the first iteration through the loop. `data` is an empty list. We append `row`, which is a list, so now `data` looks something like this:

```
data = [ <row> ] = [ [<csv0>,<csv1>,...] ]
```

Now we execute

```
        option_list1 = data[2],[1]
```

So we're retrieving `data[2]`, the second element of `data`. But `data` is currently a list of length 1. I suspect that's where your exception is coming from.

An aside: `data[2],[1]` will return the tuple `(<data[2]>, [1])`. I can't tell from this excerpt what you're looking for, but this seems odd. I like to test with sample data outside of flask, and add print statements, if that would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you have clearly identified where the problem is located, can you tell me how to make data become a list of length 2 in order to loop through row and columns ?

Comment: You may need to better understand the values in your variables. Perhaps print/log statements that show you the contents of `data` and `row` would help.